# How to increase the Cypher query character limit?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is there any way to increase the query character limit? I have create queries that are over 9000 characters. The error that I receive is:

```
Cypher query must be shorter than 5000 characters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `memgraph-platform`, this ENV variable needs to be added:

```
docker run .... -e APP_CYPHER_QUERY_MAX_LEN=10000 memgraph/memgraph-platform
```

Other Memgraph Lab configuration parameters are:

```
# Max limit for the Cypher query
APP_CYPHER_QUERY_MAX_LEN=5000
# Max limit for the query module name
APP_MODULE_NAME_MAX_LEN=1000
# Max limit for the query module content
APP_MODULE_CONTENT_MAX_LEN=50000
# Max name for the stream name
APP_STREAM_NAME_MAX_LEN=500
```